# Read and separate data from a text file

Tags: c#

I am having some issues trying to figure out how to read each line in a text file. The text file is used to store media objects such as books, songs and movies. Each media has a title, year, author/artist, and some have summaries that are encoded in rot13. I can read the lines that start with BOOK, SONG, MOVIE and used an if statement to read those lines and put the contents in to an array depending on the media type but I am not sure how to put the summaries along with the media type as it reads each line since I don't have if statements to check for lines that do not start with the media type. Text file and C# code below:

Data.txt:

> BOOK|The Fellowship of the Ring|1954|J.R.R. Tolkien
>
> Fnheba, gur Qnex Ybeq, unf tngurerq gb uvz nyy gur Evatf bs Cbjre rkprcg bar - gur Bar Evat gung ehyrf gurz nyy - juvpu unf snyyra vagb gur unaqf bs gur uboovg Ovyob Onttvaf. Lbhat Sebqb Onttvaf svaqf uvzfrys snprq jvgu na vzzrafr gnfx jura Ovyob ragehfgf gur Evat gb uvf pner. Sebqb zhfg znxr n crevybhf wbhearl npebff Zvqqyr-rnegu gb gur Penpxf bs Qbbz, gurer gb qrfgebl gur Evat naq sbvy gur Qnex Ybeq va uvf rivy checbfr.

---

> SONG|Fly Me to the Moon|1964|It Might as Well be Swing|Frank Sinatra

---

> MOVIE|The Princess Bride|1987|Rob Reiner
>
> N xvaqyl tenaqsngure fvgf qbja jvgu uvf tenaqfba naq ernqf uvz n orqgvzr fgbel. Gur fgbel vf bar gung unf orra cnffrq qbja guebhtu sebz sngure gb fba sbe trarengvbaf. Nf gur tenaqsngure ernqf gur fgbel, gur npgvba pbzrf nyvir. Gur fgbel vf n pynffvp gnyr bs ybir naq nqiragher nf gur ornhgvshy Ohggrephc vf xvqanccrq naq uryq ntnvafg ure jvyy va beqre gb zneel gur bqvbhf Cevapr Uhzcreqvapx, naq Jrfgyrl (ure puvyqubbq ornh, abj erghearq nf gur Qernq Cvengr Eboregf) nggrzcgf gb fnir ure. Ba gur jnl ur zrrgf na nppbzcyvfurq fjbeqfzna naq n uhtr, fhcre fgebat tvnag, obgu bs jubz orpbzr uvf pbzcnavbaf va uvf dhrfg. Gurl zrrg n srj onq thlf nybat gur jnl gb erfphr Ohggrephc.

C# script:

```
FileStream mediaFile = new FileStream("Data.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader mediaData = new StreamReader(mediaFile);

string mediaRow; // temporary variable to hold the string data for each row

while ((mediaRow = mediaData.ReadLine()) != null) // as long as there is more string data, the loop while continue
{
    if (mediaRow.StartsWith("BOOK"))
    {
        string[] dataSplit = mediaRow.Split('|');

        int year = 0;

        bool didConvert = Int32.TryParse(dataSplit[2].Trim(), out year);

        if (!didConvert)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Year conversion error");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        books[bookCount] = new Book(dataSplit[1].Trim(), year, dataSplit[3].Trim());
        media[mediaCount] = books[bookCount];

        bookCount++;
        mediaCount++;
    }
    else if (mediaRow.StartsWith("SONG"))
    {
        string[] dataSplit = mediaRow.Split('|');

        int year = 0;

        bool didConvert = Int32.TryParse(dataSplit[2].Trim(), out year);

        if (!didConvert)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Year conversion error");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        songs[songCount] = new Song(dataSplit[1].Trim(), year, dataSplit[3].Trim(), dataSplit[4].Trim());
        media[mediaCount] = songs[songCount];

        songCount++;
        mediaCount++;
    }
    else if (mediaRow.StartsWith("MOVIE"))
    {
        string[] dataSplit = mediaRow.Split('|');

        int year = 0;

        bool didConvert = Int32.TryParse(dataSplit[2].Trim(), out year);

        if (!didConvert)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Year conversion error");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        movies[movieCount] = new Movie(dataSplit[1].Trim(), year, dataSplit[3].Trim());
        media[mediaCount] = movies[movieCount];

        movieCount++;
        mediaCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that whole thing just one text file? If yes, why have you formatted it like that?

Comment: Is the summary a single line? Or multiple lines? Either way, you need to keep track of what the last line with a media type was so you know where to put the summary.

Comment: this is not that difficult.. are you aware of the many free resources out there that yield tons of working examples in regards to reading a TextFile and Splitting a Textfile. do a google search on the following 
`String.Split() and `ReadAllText Method(s)` can you edit your question and post a more accurate sample of the text file.. it appears that you have multiple delimiters ..if so then this is also very easy to split a string based on multiple delimiters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Movie`, `Song` and `Book` are all sharing some common base class that is what the `media` array is (let's guess it's called `Media`). You just need to keep track of the `Media` instance you are dealing with. So, something like:

```
Media currentItem = null;
while ((mediaRow = mediaData.ReadLine()) != null) // as long as there is more string data, the loop while continue
{
     if (mediaRow.StartsWith("BOOK"))
     {
         // Do you book processing...
         books[bookCount] = new Book(dataSplit[1].Trim(), year, dataSplit[3].Trim());
         currentItem = books[bookCount];
         // ....
     }
     else if (mediaRow.StartsWith("SONG"))
     {
         // Do song processing
     } 
     else if (mediaRow.StartsWith("MOVIE"))
     {
         // Do movie processing
     }
     else
     {
         // this must be a summary for the previous item
         // assuming Media has a summary property:
         currentItem.Summary = mediaRow;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, having to track of the current media makes a lot more sense. I really appreciate your prompt response :)